# how to transparent background color label over Picturebox dynamic in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

how to ransparent background  color label over button dynamic in c#?

```cs
Label titre= new Label();

PictureBox btnimage = new PictureBox();

btnimage.Name = "img" + i;

btnimage.Location = new Point(19, 15);

btnimage.Size = new Size(170, 153);

btnimage.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;

// type annonces

titre.Name = "name" + i;

titre.Text = systeme.Annonces[i].name.ToString();

titre.ForeColor = Color.Black;

titre.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

titre.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 9, FontStyle.Bold);

titre.Location = new Point(23, 125);
```

Comment: firstly can we ask _why_ you want to do this? Are you trying to make the box unclickable, or change its colour, or add text to it, or something? Because there are far better ways to do that.

Comment: basically, this could work. pay attention to zorder. I think pictureboxes are even containers for child controls, so you could add the label to it.  but would you not rather paint the text of the label into the picture box instead?

Comment: I want to change its color

Answer (score -1):

```
titre.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
```

Fair warning, transparency in WinForms is not fully supported.

Comment: It doesn't work with me because (titre) above (Picturebox)

Comment: Please elaborate on how it doesn't work and your end goal.  A screen grab will help.

Comment: look at the picture  here https://i.stack.imgur.com/jneya.png

Comment: Make sure you are adding the label to the picture box's controls, not the form's controls.  Based on the picture and the info provided, it looks like the form is the label's parent.

Comment: Why the downvote?  This achieved the desired result in my testing.